# Exposing Active Directory Groups on ArcGIS Server 10.2.2

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, authentication

Is there a way to have ArcGIS Server 10.2.2 expose Active Directory Groups and users instead of just users?  I have IIS and the Server set up for Windows Authentication (IIS) and Web Authentication (ArcGIS server).  I'm looking to secure services whereby only members of certain Active Directory groups we have set up in the organization can access.  This would be preferred to the only option I have seen so far - creating a role wmanually selecting each user

Comment: AD roles are available in 10.2. That is how I have done it.

Comment: @BradNesom, you meant 10.3, didn't you?

Comment: As of right now - I create a role named after the AD Group in question, but I then have to add the relevant users manually as ArcGIS Server does not detect the Active Directory Groups we have stored within our domain.  So, while I can add John Doe, I cannot see thisagency_gis_adgroupname_r.